# Rspec factory girl issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I have an rspec/factory girl test where I can't get a test to pass.

I'm using devise where current_user calls the currently logged in User model.

I can load up a test console and type in

```
u = Factory(:user)
u.company
```

And this will return a valid company but for some reason in rspec calling current_user.company is returning nil.

Any ideas?

**Controller**

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :authenticate_user!

   def show
     @company = current_user.company
   end
end
```

**Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, :case_sensitive => false

  has_one :company
end
```

**Factory**

```
Factory.define :company do |f|
  f.name 'Test Company'
end

Factory.sequence(:email) do |n| 
  "person#{n}@example.com"
end

Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.name 'Test User'
  f.email {Factory.next :email}
  f.password 'password'
  f.company Factory(:company)
end
```

**Test**

```
describe CompaniesController do
  before(:each) do
    @user = Factory(:user)
    sign_in @user
  end

  describe "GET show" do
    before do
      get :show
    end

    it "should find the users company" do
      assigns(:company).should be_a(Company)
    end
  end
end
```

**Spec Helper**

```
RSpec.configure do |config|      
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
end
```

**Test Result**

```
Failures:

  1) CompaniesController GET show should find the users company
     Failure/Error: assigns(:company).should be_a(Company)
       expected nil to be a kind of Company(id: integer, name: string, user_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
       # ./spec/controllers/companies_controller_spec.rb:21:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

EDIT

I have removed the f.company = Factory(:company) in the factories file. And made my controller spec this

require 'spec_helper'

```
describe CompaniesController do     
  let(:current_user) { Factory(:user) }

  before(:each) do    
    sign_in current_user

    current_user.company = Factory(:company)
    current_user.save
  end

  describe "GET show" do
    before do
      get :show
    end

    it "should find the users company" do
      current_user.should respond_to(:company)
      assigns(:company).should == current_user.company
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define Let object for company in your controller rspec.

```
describe CompaniesController do
  describe "authorizations" do
   before(:each) do
    let(:company) { Factory :company }
    let(:user_admin) { Factory(:user) }
   end

   it "should redirect" do
    sign_in(user_admin)
    get :show
   end

   it "should find the users company" do
     assigns(:company).should be_a(company)
   end
 end
end
```

Can you try with above spec ?

Comment: I don't think you can use let in the before block.

I went in this direction though, I'll append my code to my main post

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I believe assigns(:company) checks for an instance variable `@company` which obviously doesn't exist. Try putting `@company = @user.company` in your `before(:each)` block or test for it in another way, for example;

```
it "should find the users company" do
  @user.should respond_to(:company)
end
```

I believe that should do it!

Answer (score 0):

I think the main thing you were missing is setting up an *association* in your factory. Starting from your original example:

```
Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.name 'Test User'
  f.email {Factory.next :email}
  f.password 'password'
  f.association :company, factory => :company
end
```

Then when you create a user, it will create a company and fill in user.company_id with the proper id.

See "Associations" in the [Factory Girl Getting Started](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) doc.